# Add Eventhandlers in VB.Net like C# does in constructor?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a code snippet in C# which i want to convert into VB.Net

```
public class ModuleAViewOne : UserControl
{
    public ModuleAViewOne(ModuleAViewOneViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.DataContext = model;
        }
    }
}
```

I converted it into VB.Net this way

```
Partial Public Class ModuleAViewOne
 Inherits UserControl

Public Sub New(ByVal model As ModuleAViewOneViewModel)
        InitializeComponent()

        Me.model = model

        AddHandler Loaded, AddressOf _Loaded
    End Sub

    Dim model As ModuleAViewOneViewModel

    Private Sub _Loaded(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        DataContext = model
    End Sub
End Class
```

but can event be written inside constructor so that I do not have to create a new global `model` variable?

Comment: These are just lambda expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: @Nick: I know that but my question is not that.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal What then if not that? You can have statement lambdas as of VB2010, so write one instead of the `AddressOf` bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a lambda expression

```
Public Sub New(model As ModuleAViewOneViewModel)
    InitializeComponent()

    AddHandler Loaded, Sub(s, e) DataContext = model
End Sub
```

---

Or, since VB 10.0 (shipped with Visual Studio 2010), you can use a multiline lambda:

```
Public Sub New(model As ModuleAViewOneViewModel)
    InitializeComponent()

    AddHandler Loaded, Sub(s, e) 
                          DataContext = model
                       End Sub
End Sub
```